# free_result() with MY_Model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a get dunction inside a MY_Model I'm trying to create, which returns either a single record or all records. What I'd like to do is when I get the result(s) to ALWAYS free some memory with free_result(), but if i put it in the line i return the result, I got nothing. Any suggestions please?

```
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

        if ($id != NULL) {

            $filter = $this->_primary_filter; // filter the id
            $id = $filter($id); // e.g. intval($id)

            $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);

            $method = 'row'; // single record
        } elseif ($single === TRUE) {
            $method = 'row'; // single record
        } else {
            $method = 'result'; // all records
        }
        return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't free memory with results before you use results in controller. It is possible results are returned not by value but pointer/reference so results are in the same place in memory all the time till page is rendered.

Using `free_result()` you destroy results before they are used in controller.

Btw: it is possible that results are send to View also as pointer/reference so it can happened you get page without results if you destroy results in controller before page is rendered.

Comment: is there a way that i can use the free_result() before i return the results to the controller??

Comment: No, you can't. You can't destroy results before you use in controller. I think `return` doesn't even duplicate results so you don't have results twice in memory. You have only one copy all the time. And after rendering page PHP should free all memory used by Model, Controller and View.